# Xamarin Forms INavigation se queda pillado

Tags: xamarin.forms, push, pop

Estoy desarrollando mi primera aplicación para móvil con Xamarin Forms. Para la navegabilidad quise desarrollar un menú de tabs en la parte de abajo (parecido al funcionamiento de Instagram) en el que tienes "pestañas" dentro de cada tab, pero ocasionalmente puedes entrar en pestañas que se superpongan al menu principal. Con esa idea en mente lo enfoqué de la siguiente manera:

- Un **MainNavigation** (*INavigation*) ligado a un *ContentPage* **MainView**.
- Un **PrincipalPage** (*TabbedPage*) ligado a un *TabbedPage* **MainTab**.
- Cada tab del **PrincipalPage** tiene su propio *INavigation* ligado a sus respectivos *ContentPage*.
- El **MainNavigation** nunca debería tener menos de 2 elemento en su NavigationStack (el **MainView** y el **MainTab**) pero se le pueden añadir otros *ContentPage*.

Creé la siguiente clase que se encarga de hacer los *push* y *pop* dependiendo de la situación:

```
 static class Navigator
{
    internal static INavigation MainNavigation { get; set; }
    internal static TabbedPage PrincipalPage { get; set; }
    internal static INavigation NavigationLibrary { get; set; }
    ...

    public static void ClosedJourneysView(ObservableCollection<Journey> closedJourneys)
    {
        ResetAll();
        NavigationLibrary.PushAsync(new ClosedView(closedJourneys));
    }

    public static void CreateJourney()
    {
        // MainNavigation porque tiene que sobresalir a la parte de abajo
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Navigator profundidad : " + MainNavigation.NavigationStack.Count);
        MainNavigation.PushAsync(new CreateJourneyView());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Navigator profundidad : " + MainNavigation.NavigationStack.Count);
    }

    ...

    public static void Pop()
    {
        INavigation nav = GetCurrentNavigation();
        if ( (nav.Equals(MainNavigation) && nav.NavigationStack.Count > 2)
                || nav.NavigationStack.Count > 1)
        {
            nav.PopAsync();
        }
    }

    ...

    internal static INavigation GetCurrentNavigation()
    {
        if ( MainNavigation.NavigationStack.Count > 2 )
        {
            return MainNavigation;
        }
        else if ( PrincipalPage.CurrentPage.Equals(PrincipalPage.Children[0]) )
        {
            return NavigationLibrary;
        }

        ...

    }

    internal static void ResetAll()
    {
        NavigationLibrary.PopToRootAsync();
        ...
    }
}
```

Realizando las pruebas, me vi con el problema cuando intento añadir una nueva "capa" al **MainNavigation**. Este es un extracto de las pruebas:

```
[TestMethod]
private static void NavigatorTest()
{
        // Test ClosedJourneysView
        Navigator.ClosedJourneysView(new ObservableCollection<Journey> { new Journey(), new Journey() });
        Assert.AreEqual(2, Navigator.MainNavigation.NavigationStack.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(Navigator.PrincipalPage.Children[0], Navigator.PrincipalPage.CurrentPage);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, Navigator.PrincipalPage.CurrentPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Navigator profundidad : " + Navigator.NavigationLibrary.NavigationStack.Count); //Aquí es 2, correcto.
        Navigator.Pop();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Navigator profundidad : " + Navigator.NavigationLibrary.NavigationStack.Count); //Aquí es 1, correcto.

        // Test CreateJourney
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Navigator profundidad : " + Navigator.MainNavigation.NavigationStack.Count); //Aquí es 2, correcto.
        Navigator.CreateJourney();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Navigator profundidad : " + Navigator.MainNavigation.NavigationStack.Count); //Aquí es 3, correcto.
        Navigator.Pop();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Navigator profundidad : " + Navigator.MainNavigation.NavigationStack.Count); //Sigue siendo 3
        Navigator.CreateJourney();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Navigator profundidad : " + Navigator.MainNavigation.NavigationStack.Count); //Sigue siendo 3
        Navigator.Pop();
}
```

Esta funcionalidad había conseguido que funcionase, sin embargo dejó de funcionar en algún punto al que no soy capaz de volver.

La salida de la ejecución correspondiente al trozo donde deja de funcionar (se queda pillado en 3) es el siguiente, sin ningún tipo de error:

```
12-24 11:09:22.824 D/Mono    (17340): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_new_local_ref'.
12-24 11:09:22.824 D/Mono    (17340): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_new_local_ref'.
[0:] Navigator profundidad : 3
[0:] Navigator profundidad : 3
Resolved pending breakpoint at 'C:\Users\...\Travelogue\Main\Utils\Navigator.cs:233,1' to void Travelogue.Main.Domain.Utils.Navigator.Pop () [0x00001].
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #16
[0:] Navigator profundidad : 3
[0:] Navigator profundidad : 3
```

¿Alguien se le ocurre qué puede estar pasando o cómo puedo depurarlo para que de algún tipo de salida con mas información sobre por qué no funciona? Muchas gracias.

Comment: No termino de comprender tu problema. Que es lo que te sucede? quien setea tu INavigation para que no sea null? y porque no usas Shell si queres el menu abajo.

Comment: Mi problema es que a partir de la linea "Navigator.CreateJourney();" en el test, el INavigation se queda pillado, ni añade ni quita capas al MainNavigation.NavigationStack. Los INavigation son enlazados en la creación del ContentPage MainView y el TabbedPage MainTab. Y no use shell porque lo desconocía completamente, gracias por la info, le echaré un ojo.